# TypeError: Cannot read property 'signInWithPhoneNumber' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

result is defined but never used error occur but i can used see in code.

and another occur in console 'Cannot read property 'signInWithPhoneNumber' of undefined'

```
sendOTP(){
     if(this.phoneNo.length!=10){
         alert('Invalid No.');
     }else{
         let countryCode="+91"
         let phoneNumber=countryCode+ this.phoneNo
         let appVerifier=this.appVerifier

         firebase.auth.signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
         .then(function (confirmationResult){
             window.confirmationResult=confirmationResult;
             alert('SMS sent')
         }).catch(function(){
             alert('SMS not sent')
         })
     }
 },
```

Comment: You need `()` after `auth`. So `firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the first error, it's just a linting warning that you defined a variable `result` somewhere and you are not using.

Moreover, the second error is because `firebase.auth` does not exist, which would be probably solved by importing it and using it as follows:

```
import Firebase from 'firebase';
```

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber...
```

Comment: i can import firebase i forget to write

Comment: verifyOTP(){
        if(this.phoneNo.length!=10||this.otp.length!=6){
            alert('Invalid format')
        }
        else{
            let vm=this
            let code=this.otp
             //var user
            window.confirmationResult.confirm(code).then(function (result){
                var user = user.result
                vm.$router.push({path:'/home'})
            })
        }
    },

Comment: @AdiYadav yes you are passing it in ``then(function (result)`` but never used it. you can either remove it or print it in the console, or change your linting rules

Comment: what about second problem

Comment: replace ``auth`` with ``auth()`` and do not forget to import ``firebase``

Comment: Please mark the answer as the solution in order for others to see it as well

Comment: firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.auth is not a function occur when i replace